# How to submit multiple spark queries parallel using SqlContext

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to run multiple spark SQL parallel in a spark cluster, so that I can **utilize the complete resource**. I'm using `sqlContext.sql(query)`.

**EDITS**

I saw some sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056831/how-can-i-parallelize-different-sparksql-execution-efficiently/50058194#50058194) like follows,

```
val parallelism = 10
val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism)
val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(executor)
val tasks: Seq[String] = ???
val results: Seq[Future[Int]] = tasks.map(query => {
  Future{
    //spark stuff here
    0
  }(ec)
})
val allDone: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future.sequence(results)
//wait for results
Await.result(allDone, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)
executor.shutdown //otherwise jvm will probably not exit
```

As I understood, the **ExecutionContext** compute the available cores in the machine(using **ForkJoinPool**) and do the parallelism accordingly.
But what happens if we consider the spark cluster other-than the single machine and How can it guarantee the complete cluster resource utilization.?

eg: If I have a 10 node cluster with each 4 cores, then how can the above code guarantees that the 40 cores will be utilized.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But that question is unanswered. Also a sample code will be more helpful.

Comment: Here you are: [How can I parallelize different SparkSQL execution efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50058194/9613318)

Comment: Waw, thats very much helpful. Thank you. Will try the same. :)

Comment: If you search, you'll find a bunch of other similar questions, some probably with better answers. There is for example [Processing multiple files as independent RDD's in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31912858/9613318). My search skills are just not top-notch today :)