# How to run batch hive queries in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am executing multiple hive queries in a loop from my spark job using the following piece of code

```
implicit val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

 val bizEventFolders = fs.listStatus(outputPath)
    bizEventFolders.foreach(folder => {
      val filePath = folder.getPath().toString
      if(filePath.contains(outputDir+"biz_evnt_key=")){
        val bizEventKey = filePath.replaceAll(outputDir+"biz_evnt_key=","")
        val addPartitionHiveQuery = s"alter table $tableName add if not exists partition (year=$year, month=$month, day=$day, hr=$hour,biz_evnt_key=$bizEventKey) location '${outputDir}biz_evnt_key=$bizEventKey'"
        sparkSession.sql(addPartitionHiveQuery)
        logger.info(s"successfully ran add partition hive query $addPartitionHiveQuery")
      }
    })
```

problem is, I have to run multiple such queries one after the other for adding all the partitions to the HIVE table, how can I submit all the queries at once to spark instead of firing them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scala Futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056831/how-can-i-parallelize-different-sparksql-execution-efficiently) or another parallel AP to run those queries in parallel.

A simple solution might be using [par](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html):

```
bizEventFolders.par.foreach(folder => {
      val filePath = folder.getPath().toString
      if(filePath.contains(outputDir+"biz_evnt_key=")){
        val bizEventKey = filePath.replaceAll(outputDir+"biz_evnt_key=","")
        val addPartitionHiveQuery = s"alter table $tableName add if not exists partition (year=$year, month=$month, day=$day, hr=$hour,biz_evnt_key=$bizEventKey) location '${outputDir}biz_evnt_key=$bizEventKey'"
        sparkSession.sql(addPartitionHiveQuery)
        logger.info(s"successfully ran add partition hive query $addPartitionHiveQuery")
      }
    })
```

By invoking the `par` method on the sequential collection (list for example), it becomes a parallel collection and one can use it in the same way as it was a sequential collection.